# Bad UX when scrolling individual job ad

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, user-experience

When you scroll individual job posting on Stackoverflow Careers and you hit the *breaking point* top company information changes from static display to fixed top positioned bar.

This is great as long as the whole ad wouldn't re-position due to changed element positioning. This is very distracting as user can't simply read the ad forward but rather needs to first find the point where they were in text and then read on.

### How to improve UX?

Ad content should change its top margin/padding to compensate for the re-positioned company info header re-positioning from static to fixed so text wouldn't jump up/down.

Comment: Alternatively, don't remove the copy at the top - use a quick `.cloneNode()` if need be to make a copy of it and `fixed`-position that one instead.

Comment: I added the feature-request tag. If you feel that's not accurate, please revert it.